# How to finish a wall over a curb?

Tags: drywall, baseboard

I am turning a detached garage into a workshop. So I'm insulating it and putting up drywall. The issue is all of the walls sit on top of a 3.5 inch curb of concrete. I don't live in an area where water is a major problem but I'm still hesitant to just run the drywall right to the concrete floor. I was thinking of just running a 1x6 board glued/nailed to the base of the wall and just run the drywall to the top of that. My question is do I have to use pressure treated? Or would a stained/sealed board hold up okay?

Also open if anyone has any better ideas for how to handle the curb.

[image: image of yhe bottom of the wall/curb]

Comment: Edited to add photo and be a little more clear. Yes the wood framing sits flush with the concrete

Comment: I would set a 2x4 on edge on the floor to use as a support for hanging the drywall so that the drywall sits flush with the bottom of the bottom plate, then pull the 2x4 out and use it to set the next piece of drywall. Properly screwed drywall will hang just fine without being supported underneath. For that rare occasion when you might get water in the shop, or if you ever decide to clean the floor and put in an epoxy floor coating, the drywall won't get damaged.

Comment: What is wrong with the typical "drywall from the top, then cover the bottom gap with molding"? PVC molding is super cheap and will make the area look almost as nice as a room in your house. Or even, since it's a garage, just leaving the gap between the concrete and the bottom of the drywall? Are aesthetics a factor here?

Comment: @Txcsm PS, unrelated to your question, but looking at your photo, that second bolt in from the left edge looks like it needs to be tightened significantly; the sill plate shouldn't have that much room between it and the sill gasket, or the gasket won't perform its intended function at all.

Comment: @tylerH anesthetics aren't the biggest factor but still trying to make it look decent. And yes I know about tightening the anchor. I inherited this project after the fact so actually just sunk that anchor to try to correct the board. Waiting on epoxy to fully cure before I tightened all the way.

Answer (score 2):

For the situation shown, I'd put a strip of cementboard at the bottom, same thickness as the drywall, and drywall above that. Actually, I'd prefer plywood above that for a workshop, - current prices are an issue though.

Cementboard is water-resistant, and it stands up to minor bumps better than drywall.

@Freemans suggestion is also valid if you don't mind having a small step at the bottom of the wall surface.

If using a board, as you ask, I follow the rule that all wood in contact with concrete should be pressure-treated. Or in *this* case plastic trim lumber would also be fine.

Though it looks like your bottom plate is not treated...But I guess it's sitting on sill-seal, so not direct contact.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider it important to cover the shorty wall, so I'd just lap the drywall onto the concrete a short distance to cover the joint--say an inch--and call it good. It ain't a museum. If you're finishing the drywall you could install a U-channel along the bottom first (or later).

Ideally you'll end up with a nice straight line, so if your slab has a slope you may want to snap a chalk line down a bit less than the lap, then measure and cut to that.